# Performance difference between select() vs WSAEventSelect() vs WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()

Tags: c++, winsock2

I have an application that is using a cross platform library developed internally.
For various reasons I must stick with using this library under windows at least.

That library contains a socket class that I have to use and it's calling select.

I have the ability to modify the library a little.
Would there be a performance improvement if going to WSAWaitForMultipleEvents or WSAEventSelect?

Bear in mind that the client library is based on a blocking I/O.

i.e. it calls select to check read first before issuing recvfrom, and the same for writing.

From what I can see there is quite a lot of set up just for select and wondered if I might improve the polling speed by going to the windows native versions as my UDP server which is linux based is occasionally overwealming my receiver which stalls it. i.e. the receiver while not doing a lot has trouble keeping up.  Increasing the receive buffers has helped enormously but now I'm looking at select.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but if it's that touch and go, you might also want to consider having a separate thread looping on recvfrom() so the operating system wakes it as soon as input's available... saves all the hassles with socket descriptor sets etc..

Comment: It already is in it's own thread. I'd rather not have 2 threads for receiving.

Comment: Part of the performance problem might be to do with virtual box.  The server is native linux, the client is a VM.